# How does the back-end of the upcoming MyMonero app look like?

Tags: mymonero

I was wondering if the backend (that I understand fluffypony will be running) will be just a regular full node. If not, how does it differ from a regular full node?

Also, could I run the MyMonero app against my own full node instead of fluffypony's backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/moneroexamples/openmonero) for one working open-source implementation.

As understood, it is planned to release "official" open-source [backend as well:](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js#what-is-mymonero)

> In fact, in the near future, even the above trade-off will be eliminated as we're presently working to open-source a version of the back-end, which anybody can run as their own server at home.

There's a [plan](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js/blob/master/docs/ROADMAP.md) for some back-end overhaul as well:

> In progress by vtnerd Complete overhaul of back-end, and replacement of polling with sweet push-based synchronization (Issue #46)

So yeah, the plan is to let everyone run their own back-end, as indicated [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6901k1/uendogenic_tweets_the_mymonero_app_source_code_is/dh2lw4u/). Quoting fluffypony:

> He's done excellent, excellent work - we've spent months on this, and hopefully it'll make MyMonero a significantly safer service to use, especially when you use it with your own node.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting! Have some follow up questions which are too long to post as a comment here, will open a new question for that.

Comment: Follow up question here: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/mymonero-architecture-question-blockchain-scanning-put-into-backend-mainly-to-s